# run dependant tests with pytest

Tags: pytest, pytest-dependency, pytest-markers

With pytest, I'm setting dependencies using the library [`pytest-dependency`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-dependency/). I also add markers to those tests. Here is an ECM :

```py
# test_test.py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.dependency()
def test_a():
   assert True

@pytest.mark.category
@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=['test_a'])
def test_b():
   assert True
```

with the `pytest.ini` file to set the marker :

```
; pytest.ini
[pytest]
markers =
    category: category of tests.
```

When I try to run the test with the marker, as it is dependant on `test_a` which doesn't have the marker `category`, it is skipped :

```
user@pc → [~/Documents/test] $ pytest -vv -k category
============================================== test session starts ===============================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.8, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/saigre/Documents/test, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: dependency-0.5.1
collected 2 items / 1 deselected / 1 selected

test_test.py::test_b SKIPPED (test_b depends on test_a)                                                    [100%]

======================================== 1 skipped, 1 deselected in 0.05s ========================================
```

Is there a way to *force* the run of `test_a` because of the dependency.
A solution would be to add the marker to the first test, but it would be complicated for the case I'm working on...

**EDIT for @MrBean Bremen :** I made an example of the scheme of dependency
[image: scheme]
If I want to add a marker on a test, I would have to put this marker on all the branches, and the "root" would have many markers. It is not that it is complicated to do, but tedious.

Comment: If you filter by markers, this is not possible, AFAIK. Can you elaborate on why you can't add the marker to `test_a`?

Comment: @MrBean Bremen, I edited the post to explain it

Comment: I see. The only other possibility I see (aside from just adding the markers) is to add the markers programmatically, for example in `pytest_collection_modifyitems` using `item.addmarker()`, but for that, you would have to know or detect the dependencies in that place, which is probably not easier. Or write a plugin that automatically copies markers to dependent tests...

Comment: I am also searching for something that would add the dependent test cases automatically if not explicitly selected.

Comment: I am also facing same, when we filter with marker, `pytest` should know, this marker is depend on `test_a` then it should run `test_a` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this (something similar I have implemented):

Put all your test from the same category in a class, which inherits from a base class that has `test_a`. Put each class in a separate file, and pass that specific file to `pytest`. This way, you can get rid of markers as well.

Consider a pseudo example:

```py
# tests/test_a.py #
import pytest

class TestA:

    @pytest.mark.dependency(name="TEST-A")
    def test_a(self):
        print("TEST-A was called")
        assert False


# tests/test_b.py #
import pytest
from tests.test_a import TestA

class TestB(TestA):

    def test_b1(self):
        print("TEST-B1 was called")
        assert True

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["TEST-A"])
    def test_b2(self):
        print("TEST-B2 was called")
        assert True
```

Now, on CLI, just do this:
`$ pytest tests/test_b.py`

```
tests/test_b.py::TestB::test_a <- tests/test_a.py FAILED                      [ 33%]
tests/test_b.py::TestB::test_b1 PASSED                                        [ 66%]
tests/test_b.py::TestB::test_b2 SKIPPED (test_b2 depends on TEST-A)           [100%]

===================================== FAILURES ======================================
___________________________________ TestB.test_a ____________________________________

self = <tests.test_b.TestB object at 0x7fc21886db20>

    @pytest.mark.dependency(name="TEST-A")
    def test_a(self):
        print("TEST-A was called")
>       assert False
E       assert False

tests/test_a.py:8: AssertionError
------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------
TEST-A was called
====================================== PASSES =======================================
___________________________________ TestB.test_b1 ___________________________________
------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------
TEST-B1 was called
============================== short test summary info ==============================
PASSED tests/test_b.py::TestB::test_b1
SKIPPED [1] ...: test_b2 depends on TEST-A
FAILED tests/test_b.py::TestB::test_a - assert False
====================== 1 failed, 1 passed, 1 skipped in 0.19s =======================
```